# Limiting variance of normal mean

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, asymptotics

In Casella's [Statistical Inference](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/8131503941)，in Example 10.1.8 on page 470, it says that the limiting variance of normal mean $\bar X_n$, is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt n\text{Var}\bar X_n=\sigma^2$. However, since $\bar X_n$ is iid normal mean, we have $\text{Var}\bar X_n=\sigma^2/n$, hence the limiting variance is $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\text{Var}\bar X_n=\sigma^2$.

So, is it a typo in the book or I misunderstood something?

Thanks

Comment: I checked the source and found what you refer to. I share the confusion with you. Perhaps it is a typo.

Comment: (The late) George Casella has an errata sheet for the book on his website. Unfortunately, no entry is present for page 470.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about a general estimator $T_n$ of a parameter $\theta$. Consider $ n^{1/2} (T_n - \theta) / \sigma \rightarrow_d N(0,1)$ which is the same as $ n^{1/2} (T_n - \theta) \rightarrow_d N(0,\sigma^2)$. Here $\sigma^2$ is referred to as the asymptotic variance of $T_n$.

From CLT, $ \bar{X}_n \dot \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2/n)$. This means that
$$n^{1/2} (\bar{X}_n - \mu) / \sigma \rightarrow_d N(0,1)$$
or
$$n^{1/2} (\bar{X}_n - \mu)  \rightarrow_d N(0,\sigma^2)$$
which implies also that $ \bar{X}_n - \mu = O_p (n^{-1/2})$. The limiting variance is $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} V \{n^{1/2} (\bar{X}_n - \mu )\} = 
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} V (n^{1/2} \bar{X}_n) = 
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n V(\bar{X}_n) = 
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n \frac{\sigma^2}{n} = \sigma^2$$

Comment: What does your very first "it" refer to? The book or the OP? While I don't have the text handy to check, if it's written as described in the OP, then the $\sqrt n$ and the $\mathrm{Var}$ are transposed, so you are arguing that the OP is correct in that there is a typo in the book.

Comment: So, it's still $\lim_{n\to\infty}nV(\bar X_n)$, as I wrote in the question, right? And therefore it's a typo on the textbook. And it seems that a couple of users here agree that it is a typo.

Comment: I guess you're right, but I won't explicitly write that the Casella-Berger has a typo, as it is the bible for me.